# getting a div to resize to the height of a <p> element

Tags: css, html

I am working on my website and I need to make some css that allows me to hav a div sticking out of the side of my main content div which aligns itself with a `p` element and resizes to fit to produce a result like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCYi6.png
can this be done using only css if i want one class to make a lot of the blue divs in the image?

EDIT: i think i wasn't clear when asking this. i need something that gets the height and vertical position of the paragraph and feeds it into the div

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to use javascript to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem in CSS, but you can achieve what you are looking for using [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Here is a simple [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1871589):

```
.wrap { background:lightblue url(image-width-of-column.png) right repeat-y; min-height:100px; overflow:hidden; width:800px;}
p { width:600px; float:left; }
.sidebar{ float:right; width:200px; }
```

Comment: well what i really need would be something that gets the height of the p element and its position and feeds it to the div. sorry if i was not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with absolute positioning in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/ya6Eq/

The trick is to use `top:0px` and `bottom:0px` for the marginal element.

CSS

```
.y {
 position: relative;
 background: #0F0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.y .x {
  background: #F00;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 80px;
}
​
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <div class='y'>
          <p>
              I am <br>
              two lines tall
          </p>
          <div class='x'>marginal</div>
      </div>
      <div class='y'>
          <p>
              I am <br>
              three lines<br>
              tall<br>
          </p>
          <div class='x'>marginal</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>​
```